# How to start working with bootstrap 3 SASS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

I want to make a website in bootstrap 3 with SASS, but I'm not getting proper guidance how I should start like, how to install sass, then how should I compile that, which are the exacts files I have to use, etc? I spend so much time on Google, YouTube, but except bootstrap getting other framework installation guidance which I don't want and even I'm using wamp server, so: How should I run my website through my localhost, can anyone guide me on this?

I desperately want to use bootstrap 3 and SASS, so kindly guide me on the following, I have downloaded latest version of SASS from twitter bootstrap, now

1. How should I start working with this files?
2. What step should I follow to work with SASS?
3. What are the steps to compile?
4. How should I run my website from localhost?

Kindly guide me step by step as per my query.

Answer (score -1):

Have you gone through this http://www.mindscapehq.com/products/web-workbench you can download and install and then the templates will be installed. 
you can then add like this.

[image: this]

it will automatically generates a css file with same name and will convert the saas styles into css on saving the saas file. you just need to add the .css file that was generated to the corresponding pages

SCSS file style:

```
.fiest
{
     width:500px;
     height:250px;
}
```

CSS file which will be generated automatically:

```
    .fiest {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px; }
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your kind reply, but this is for visual studio users, Im not using visual studio, I use Dreamweaver or Sublime Text..! So can you suggest something which is not depending on any software like this????

Comment: oh sorry thought it was in VS pls check whether this come handy http://blog.assortedgarbage.com/2012/03/using-dreamweaver-with-sass-and-less/